# How to clear Windownsets types flag on Api 29 and below

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a project and I noticed that this check   `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {` only takes care of API level 30 and above for API level 29 and below it does not. I however don't know the correct flags to use to like handle this case. For instance `else {... showStatuBar and ... show navigationBars}` any ideas on how to show status bar and navigation bar on `API level 29` and below.

```
 private fun showUI() {
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
             activity?.window?.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(true)// ensures the layout fits system window
             activity?.window?.insetsController?.show(
                 WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()
                     or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
             )
         } else {
            
            // What to add
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android oficial documentation's all version codes documented take a look at the link bellow:

[Version Codes](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES)

Follows a small example bellow, just try to adapt at will:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

  //Your code go here

} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOOLIPOP) {

  //Your code go here

} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

  //Your code go here

}
```

Or like the code versions are just a Int value you can use *ranges* and *when* instead *if*:

```
when (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
   >= 30 -> {

      //Your code go here

   }

   in 26 .. 29 -> {

      //Your code go here

   }

   in 21 .. 25 -> {

      //Your code go here

   }
}
```

References:

- https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/if-expression
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ranges.html
- https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/when-expression
- https://typealias.com/start/kotlin-conditionals/